# Creating a loop within a loop in scrapy

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, scrapy

I have two sets of code, that produce different results from `scrapy`:

included above these two below code samples:

```
b_result_list = []
b_result_page = []
```

1) `b_result_page`:

```
NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR = 'a.sb_pagN ::attr(href)'
next_page = response.css(NEXT_PAGE_SELECTOR).extract_first()
if next_page:
    yield scrapy.Request(
        response.urljoin(next_page),
        callback=self.parse
    )
    b_result_page.append(next_page)
```

Example data produced:

```
            ['b.com/search?q=site%3asite.com&first=11&FORM=PORE',
     b.com/search?q=site%3asite.com&first=21&FORM=PORE']
```

2) `b_result_list`

```
LIST_SELECTOR = '.b_algo'
for bresult in response.css(LIST_SELECTOR):
    NAME_SELECTOR = 'h2 a ::attr(href)'
    yield {
        'name': bresult.css(LIST_SELECTOR).extract(),
    }
    b_result_list.append(bresult)
```

Example data produced from this:

```
['somesite.com', 'blog.somesite.com', 'somesite.com/about/contactus.php']
```

**Question**: How can I do this (I cant quite get the logic down in my head):

Access each page in `b_result_page`, `extract links` from each `b_result_page` into `b_result_list`?

How does this code look to address **my question**?

```
for brp in b_result_page:
    LIST_SELECT = '.b_algo'
    for page_item_result in response.css(LIST_SELECT):
        NAME_SELECT = 'h2 a ::attr(href)'
        yield {
            'name' : page_item_result.css(LIST_SELECT).extract(),
        }
        b_result_list.append(page_item_result)
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds what you're asking for is exactly what [CrawlSpider](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=CrawlSpider#scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider) does

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida - do please help me with my question if you can.